# Codeigniter - Define switch case according to no of rows in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have 4 Faculties who's individual detail pages will be generated by giving argument `$fn` to the `public function current()` under `Faculty Controller`. Now I know that currently there are 4 faculties so I manually made the cases. I want to change that & generate cases upto the no of faculties in the db i.e, no. of rows in the faculty table (name of the table is "uc_faculty"). The function generates data only if faculty1..faculty4 is given as argument. In case of Null it redirects & for others it gives 404.

Controller->

```
class Faculty extends CI_Controller {

    public $data=array();

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Facultydata');
        $this->load->helper('res');
        $data['facData']=$this->Facultydata->getFacData();
    }

    public function current($fn=NULL)
    {       
        $data= $this->data;
        $this->load->view('header2',$data);
        switch ($fn) {
            case NULL:
                redirect(base_url().'/home/');
                break;
            case 'faculty1':
                $data['facData']=$this->Facultydata->getSpFacData(1);
                $this->load->view('faculty',$data);
                break;
            case 'faculty2':
                $data['facData']=$this->Facultydata->getSpFacData(2);
                $this->load->view('faculty',$data);
                break;
            case 'faculty3':
                $data['facData']=$this->Facultydata->getSpFacData(3);
                $this->load->view('faculty',$data);
                break;
            case 'faculty4':
                $data['facData']=$this->Facultydata->getSpFacData(4);
                $this->load->view('faculty',$data);
                break;
            default:
                show_404();
                break;
        }
        $this->load->view('footer',$data);
    }
}
```

Model->

```
class Facultydata extends CI_Model
{
    public $return = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function getFacData()
    {   
        $q=$this->db->get('uc_faculty');
        return $q->result();
    }

    public function getSpFacData($tI)
    {   
        $tId="1000".$tI;
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('uc_faculty');
        $this->db->where('uc_admin.adm_id',$tId);
        $this->db->join('uc_admin', 'uc_admin.adm_id = uc_faculty.fac_id');
        $q= $this->db->get();
        $error = $q->num_rows() > 0 ? FALSE : TRUE;

        if ($error === FALSE)
        {
            return $q->result();
        }
        else{
            return $error;   
        }
    }
}
```

I don't care about switch cases.. if..else is also welcome. I just need to set the no of arguments possible according to the no of rows available on the uc_faculty table

Comment: If you can get rid of 'facultyX' and keep only the 'X' (the integer) then you won't even need the switch...

Comment: the question is about looping according to row count! please answer that

Comment: There is not a single loop in code... what is your your question?

Comment: i apologize I am new to codeigniter. I might have been not clear. updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A switch is not the best way to handle this, you should try to get the number from the string, do some checks and get the results:

```
if (is_null($fn)) {
    redirect(base_url().'/home/');
} else {
    $facultyNumber = (int) explode("faculty", $fn)[1];
    if (!$facultyNumber) {
        show_404();
    } else {
        $data['facData'] = $this->Facultydata->getSpFacData($facultyNumber);
        $this->load->view('faculty', $data);
    }

}
```

Comment: it will only take upto faculty4.. so ur conditions are not proper. I emphasized on restricting the loop limit to no of rows!

Comment: What loop? @NilanjanRoy

Comment: `if (!$facultyNumber || $facultyNumber > 4)` if the OP is trying to say he needs to limit it somehow

Comment: i apologize I am new to codeigniter. I might have been not clear. updated the question.

Comment: @taxicala ur current script is close to what I want. if ($facultyNumber > rowcount){ }else{ } is what i want

Comment: So there is simply no sense in the question! If the maximum number of faculties is set on stone as 4 you can just keep your code as is. What is the reward you are aiming to achieve with reducing the cases in your switch on the fly to 3, 2 or 1 instead of 4? If the max value in one iteration is, lets say, 'faculty2', Your code will do 3 comparisons and disregard the following cases thus, implicitly, behaving as there were no more cases producing exactly the same results you seem to be trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry i was confused about what I wanted exactly. I think i will stick to taxicala's snippet & set the limit to rowcount (which is actually the problem I am facing which i am not being able to retrieve.)